# How to specify intra-asset dependency in sbt-web?

Tags: elm, sbt-web

I have developed an [sbt-web plugin for Elm language](https://github.com/sutiialex/sbt-elm) for which I used as inspiration [sbt-stylus plugin](https://github.com/huntc/sbt-stylus) from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIznJSBW-GU).

The usage is the following: In `assets/elm` directory one can put an Elm project: i.e., `*.elm` files and `elm-packages.json`. The plugin will only compile `Main.elm` if it exists, and generate a `Main.js`. `elm-make` makes sure to recursively compile only the modules that are imported by `Main.elm`.

The problem I have is that if I modify one of the modules imported by `Main.elm`, a new compilation of `Main.elm` does not get triggered by `sbt`. Could anyone tell me how to specify the other `*.elm` files as dependencies of `Main.elm` in order to trigger the compilation?

Note that I do not want to do something like:

> elm-make *.elm --output=Main.js

Thanks!

Comment: Normally it uses the import commands to find what to compile

Comment: I do understand how `elm-make` finds what to compile. The problem is that `sbt` does not know that `Main.elm` depends on those other `*.elm` files, so it does not trigger a new compilation for `Main.elm` when one of the imported `*.elm` files change.

Comment: If you use sbt-web's `syncIncremental` function, whenever you compile something, you should return a collection of read files and written files. I've got an example in my project compiling sass files ([sbt-sassify](https://github.com/irundaia/sbt-sassify))